# Unexpected behavior of query in db2

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I m executing below query on db2 and expecting output to be **Availability >> 3.50** but getting out put **Availability >> 3.50000000000000000000000000000** can any one tell me what i m missing.

```
    with abc as
(
select 1+(5.0/2.0) cag_scr
from dual
)
select NVL('Availability', 'NA')||' >> '||MAX(DECODE('Availability','Availability', trunc(cag_scr,2)))
from abc;
```

Comment: Why do you tag this with Oracle when it's about DB2? 3.50 and 3.50000000000000000000000000000 are the same numbers by the way, so where is your problem? If you want a string instead containing a formatted number, use `VARCHAR_FORMAT`.

Comment: When you ask for help on Db2 it is essential to give version and platform details. That's because the answer often  *depends* on that information.  Your Oracle-style syntax on my Db2 yields result "Availability >> 3.5" . So your configuration determines your actual result.

Answer (score 1):

The Db2 database `Varchar2 compatibility` setting influences this behaviour.

Your db cfg most likely has `Varchar2 compatibility = OFF`, which will yield the result you see.

But if the database was created correctly for Oracle compatibility then `Varchar2 compatibility = ON` which yields the result that I get (3.5).

You can change the datatype of the result of the expression, with cast or function.

For example:

When "Varchar2 compatibility = OFF":

```
values 1+(5.0/2.0) 

1                                
---------------------------------
  3.50000000000000000000000000000

  1 record(s) selected.


values (cast(1+(5.0/2.0) as decimal(4,2))) 

1     
------
  3.50

  1 record(s) selected.


values (decimal(1+(5.0/2.0),4,2))

1     
------
  3.50

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: is there any other way or formatting function available apart from change db configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! Got the solution of the problem.

```
with abc as
(
select decimal(1+(5.0/2),2) cag_scr
from dual
)
select NVL('Availability', 'NA')||' >> '||MAX(DECODE('Availability','Availability', CAST(cag_scr AS DECIMAL(20,2))))
from abc
```